# Default task outcome buttons won’t show in SharePoint 2013 task

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image][image]Created a simple list workflow in SPD 2013 with ‘Start task process’ action.  Didn't change any default values.  Plan is to assign a task to multiple users to review a document, every time user adds one to document library. All works well. My list workflow sends an e-mail to user with the assign task.

My problem is, default task outcome ( Approved, Rejected) doesn't show up on the task form.  It only shows the ‘close’ button along with other task information.

How do I get my default options to show up on the task form ?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry but how to attach a document or screen shot on this? I see an option for a link but not for an attachment

Comment: Edit your original post. In the editor ribbon you'll see a button to insert image.

Comment: Post a print from the Edit screen please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to press **Edit Item** button to see buttons you want to see - *Approve*, etc..

Comment: Thanks Robert.I got it now.  Is there a way I can give a link to the Edit form from the e-mail itself (user e-mail generated from workflow)? Default e-mail link goes to the form I displayed here. ( with the 'Close' button). I need user to see the 'Edit item' form so they can Approved/Reject the item.

Comment: My colleague was looking into that possibility but he couldn't find the solution. Please mark the answer as correct if it solves your original issue.

Comment: @Hycinth and Slaven - what was your approach to getting the ID of the created task in order to send it with the URL to the edit item form?

Comment: @SlavenSemper Hi Slaven, did you or your colleague ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Bassie Actually we did, unfortunately there is no room here in comments to describe it. I can post it as an answer if you're stil interested.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, somehow, when you edit and add some code in the page or add code in content editor webpart, in any edit form of Task lists... If you have your edit form full default, it will show task outcome options as buttons again. It happens me when I tryed to hide the Content Type field from edit form, but I have the same issue that you.

Hope this helps you in some way.